# Right way to define lambda-calculus constructors

Tags: lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

Is there a clear way to find terms in lambda-calculus? For example assume that we have a pair constructor

`pair  =  λa. λb. λf. f a b`

and we have the `fst` constructor

`fst = λp. p (λa. λb. a)`

that returns the first element of the pair , we have now to define the `snd` constructor which returns the second item of the pair. I have arrived to define it like this

`snd = λp. p (λa. λb. b)` with `snd (pair a b) = b`.

snd can be defined also as

`snd = λp. p (λb. λa. b)` ,

the question is, is there a clear way how to define new constructors?

How should man think when I have to define constructors, and how can I test that my answer is correct when I'm asked to define new constructors.

Comment: your question is actually pretty vague and wide, so if you have some specific concerns, don't hesitate to clarify about those.

Comment: hi will Ness, i know this is a wide Question , i dont have something specific , all i want to know is there a best way or something that i should take care about when defining new Constructors and how can i be sure that my new Constructor is defined the right way, i think your idea "writing definitions in the combinatory Style is a good way" , thank you very much

Comment: glad to have been of help. don't hesitate to ask more questions. happy trails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(λa. (λb. b)) x y = (λb. b) y = y
```

but

```
(λb. (λa. b)) x y = (λa. x) y = x
```

, so no, the two are not equivalent: the first definition returns its *second* argument, but the second definition returns its *first* argument.

Names do not count, except for establishing the correspondence with the arguments. Arguments' *positions* count.

As to how to think about it, I often find writing the definitions down in the *combinatory* style much easier to follow:

```
pair a b selector = selector a b

fst apair = apair first_argument_selector

snd apair = apair second_argument_selector

first_argument_selector  a b = a

second_argument_selector a b = b
```

I think this is very clear. *"A pair of `a` and `b` will, given a selector procedure, feed it `a` first, and `b`, second."* etc.

We can go back and forth between the two styles with simple syntactic transformations, e.g.:

```
second_argument_selector     a     b = b       =>
second_argument_selector     a = (λb . b)      =>
second_argument_selector = (λa . (λb . b))
```

The principle of *wishful thinking* is often very helpful: we use some functions as if they were already written; then their uses dictate us how they must be defined. Just like we did with the `first_argument_selector` and `second_argument_selector`, above.

Good names help. Visually aligning the code helps. Also, using full parenthesization (like I did at the top of the post).